# Are there any complications of the position of the oxidizer injector on Orbitec's vortex rocket engine?

Tags: rockets, fuel, oxidizer, hybrid-rocket

[Orbitec's vortex rocket engine](http://www.celestialmechanics.co.uk/vortex.html) injects oxidizer from near the nozzle up the wall of the engine chamber in a vortex. The oxidizer injector being in this position seems unusual. Are there any complications of placing the injector in this position? How does Orbitec plan to work around these issues?

[Some more (brief) information on the vortex hybrid rocket engine](http://www.orbitec.com/documents/VHRE_2006.pdf)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Right, I wasn't sure whether the residue could cling around the oxidizer injector in such a way that it could eventually cause a blockage or not. That's part of what I'm asking. I don't know enough about the particulars. I just found the position of the injector to be highly unusual.

Comment: It looks odd to me too, I wonder about the stability of their cooling vortex.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I revised the question to be more general. I was hoping to ask something specific, but since I possibly picked a bad example maybe this will be more answerable.

Comment: They show a CFD flow model image, but not the pressure model that drives the flow. I'm guessing they saw a high pressure zone ringing the exhaust port of a conventional hybrid and realized they could use it to drive flow up the walls, then back down the center. The flow looks suspiciously organized and ideal. That said, gas flow follow rules and CFD models those rules. In general, failure will be found at the edge cases - during startup and near burnout. If they can demonstrate during testing the design consistently establishes this flow pattern on startup then they may have advanced the art.

Comment: I just happened to come across this question after looking at: http://newatlas.com/orbitec-vortex-liquid-fuel-rocket-engine/24807/ and this *very very loud video!* https://youtu.be/mEOoWWlUYhc and news release: http://www.orbitec.com/documents/ORBITEC_Rocket_Launch_Test_Mojave.pdf