# What organizations correspond to the logos on this ORBITEC Vortex engine rocket?

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design, insignia

Images are from the 2012 New Atlas article [ORBITEC flight tests new vortex liquid fuel rocket engine](http://newatlas.com/orbitec-vortex-liquid-fuel-rocket-engine/24807/). One looks a bit like a US military or DoD logo, one perhaps is ATK, but I'm not sure. Is this effort a joint research project between all of these organizations?

Related question: [Are there any complications of the position of the oxidizer injector on Orbitec's vortex rocket engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18413/12102)

[image]

**above:** "The Garvey Prospector P-15 on the launch rail prior to launch" from [here](http://newatlas.com/orbitec-vortex-liquid-fuel-rocket-engine/24807/).

[image]

**above:** "Liftoff of the ORBITEC/Garvey Prospector P-15" from [here](http://newatlas.com/orbitec-vortex-liquid-fuel-rocket-engine/24807/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a higher res [picture](http://www.sae.org/dlymagazineimages/11560_15263_ACT.jpg) which let me ID the logos.

[image]

The top "patch" is the Air Force Research Lab insignia.

[image]

Then [Orbitec](http://www.orbitec.com/), then [Garvey Spacecraft Corporation](http://www.garvspace.com/), then, as you said, [ATK](http://www.atk.com/) (ATK logo apparently predates the merger with Orbital).

Comment: Sorry to accept before you're even finished posting, but this one looks like a slam-dunk to me. I didn't realize that the Orbital ATK  was only about two years ago.